# Any Chrome plugin to delete the whole <div>...</div> segment identified by its CSS class name?

Tags: html, chrome, css

[image]

For example in the webpage shown above, there were 6 segments of `<div class="ModalWrap">......</div>` and I removed 5 manually.
is there a Chrome plugin that can do this automatically (remove all 6 ) when loading the webpage from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

[Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) may fill your need; you can write CSS to alter the presentation of specific pages, sites, or universally. For your particular case, you'd target the site or page, and add CSS for

```
div.ModalWrap { display: none; }
```